# ReactJS why will this state change not render? What am I doing wrong?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import axios from 'axios';

var mode=['recent', 'alltime'];

var Button = React.createClass({
  render(){
    return <input type={this.props.type} onClick=    {this.props.onClick} text={this.props.val}/>;
  }
});

class Header extends React.Component {
  constructor(){
    super()
  }

  render(){
    return <h2>Free Code Camp Leader board</h2>
  }
}

class Leader extends React.Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      users: [],
      val: props.m,
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    var th =this;
    this.serverRequest = axios.get("https://fcctop100.herokuapp.com/api/fccusers/top/"+this.state.val).then(function(result){
      console.log(result.data);
      var leaders = result.data;
      this.setState({
        users: leaders
      });
    }.bind(this));
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.serverRequest.abort();
  }

  render(){
    return (
      <div className='container'>

        <div className="tbl">
          <table className="table">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Recent </th>
                <th>Alltime</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              {this.state.users.map(function(data, index){
                return (<tr key={index}><td><img src={data.img}    className="img img-thumbnail" width="50"/>{data.username}</td> 
                <td id='recent'>{data.recent}</td> 
                <td id='alltime'>{data.alltime}</td></tr>)
              })}
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}


class App extends React.Component{
  constructor(){
    super(),
    this.state={val: mode[0]},
    this.update= this.update.bind(this),
    this.unmount=this.unmount.bind(this)
  }

  unmount(){
    ReactDOM.unmountComponentAtNode(document.getElementById('board'))
  }

  update(){
    this.unmount();
    this.setState({val: this.state.val ===mode[0]? mode[1] : mode[0]});
  }

  render(){
    return (
      <div>
        <div className='header'>
          <Header />
          <button  onClick={this.update}  >{this.state.val==mode[0]? mode[1] : mode[0]}</button>
        </div>
        <div id="board">
          {this.state.val === mode[0]? <Leader m= {this.state.val} /> : this.state.val ===
            mode[1] ? <Leader m= {this.state.val} /> : null}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

The questionable part is under class App extends React.Component. I am trying to re-render the Leader Component with the state change in the update method. it changes states, but then does not change the property passed to Leader to rerender.

Comment: What's the purpose of calling `unmount()`. Do you have the same behaviour if you just comment that line out?

Comment: I think the issue is `componentDidMount` only invoked once, only on the client (not on the server), immediately after the initial rendering occurs.

If you move `this.state.val` to leader render it should update.

Comment: ok thanks, yeah the unmount() function was just an experiment in trying to unmount Leader before steState on the val property. currently its a useless function that needs to be removed, most likely.

Comment: Small tip: if you change the anonymous function callback in the `get` call to be `(result) => {}`, then you won't need to call `bind(this)` at the end since `=>` ("arrow") functions lexically pass `this`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not doing anything inside `Leader` with the prop `m` after it's initial render. So, it is re-rendering, but its state hasn't changed. Remember that the `constructor` is only called once, before the initial `render`. So, if you want `Leader` to respond to prop changes after the initial `render` and update its state accordingly, you need to use one of the [component lifecycle methods](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html).

I would recommend adding a [`componentWillReceiveProps` lifecycle method](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html#updating-componentwillreceiveprops) to your `Leader` component. This should do it:

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
  this.setState({ val: nextProps.m });
}
```

Any easy way to test what's happening inside your components is to just add a `console.log(this.props, this.state);` as the first line of the component's `render`.

Comment: ok, thankyou i will try that method when I get back to the computer and let you know how it works. I think that might actually do the trick.

Comment: I think this solution is good, but it's worth asking, do you need to duplicate App state into Leader? Why not just use `props.m` inside of leader?

Comment: Agreed. I'm just trying to show OP what he/she is doing wrong in their current implementation.

Comment: I am using the App state value as a property passed into Leader because the button rendered in App and the associated update method are what should determine the api call method in leader, of which there are two options that I am trying to toggle between. Are you referring to a more efficient approach to that problem?

Comment: @ChadD @azium is suggesting (and I agree), that you don't need to keep `val` in the state of `Leader`. You can replace the `... + this.state.val` with `... + this.props.m`. That way you won't need to worry about updating the `Leader`'s state of `val` when its parent passes in a new `m` prop.

Comment: @MatthewHerbst alright I am a step closer, I think. I am having to make separate ajax calls for the updates, which I have isolated into a separate function in the Leader component. the problem I am having now is that the first click of the button is going unheaded, but the subsequent ones work! which in effect is putting the the wrong button display with each ajax call.

Comment: @ChadD make a new question for it :)